# How to retrieve list item at index based on name from Json object in Python

Tags: json, string, list, dictionary

E.g. Given the following JSON:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "''",
  "result": [
    {
      "buy": [
        {
          "quantity": 12.37,
          "rate": 32.55412402
        }
      ],
      "sell": [
        {
          "quantity": 12.37,
          "rate": 32.55412402
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How would I go about retrieving the 'Buy' and 'Sell' to store into variables?
I can get the result via:

```
d = json.loads(string)

print(d['result'])
```

However I fail to see how to retrieve the buy object now. E.g. I've tried:

```
#print(d['result']['buy'])
#print(d['result'].buy)
#print(d['result'].indexOf('buy'))
```

All to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`print(d['result'][0]['buy'])`

should give you the buy object:

```
[{u'rate': 32.55412402, u'quantity': 12.37}]
```

If you inspect the `type` of `d['result']`:

```
print(type(d['result']))  # <type 'list'>
```

It's a `list` of length `1`, so the `[0]` at the end of `d['result'][0]` will return that first and only item in the list which is the dictionary you are expecting that you can get by key `['buy']` as you did in your first try:

```
#print(d['result']['buy'])
```

there just need to index the list by `[0]`

```
#print(d['result'][0]['buy'])
```

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering if there was a more explicit way of referencing it however? E.g. imagine along with 'Buy' and 'Sell' we had 1000 more entries in similar fashion, how do I go by name instead of index?

Comment: do you mean 1000 more entries in the `d['result']` list? that would be `for obj in d['result']:
    print(d['result']['buy'])`. If you really mean you have 1000 more dictionaries like `'Buy'` and `'Sell'` in the same list, something like `for key in d['result'][0].keys():
    print(d['result'][0][key])` would work. Is that what you mean? If not maybe put an example of the structure into the question and I can include it in the answer so it's readable

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity, however, for key in d['result'][0].keys(): print(d['result'][0][key]) was what I was after accomplishing. Thank you!